# How to set up NDK on Intellij

Tags: opencv, intellij-idea, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am having a lot of trouble getting the android ndk and jni to work with intellij.

Could someone please guide me through it.

I have looked at other questions, and cannot find anything informative or that I understand. I konw it is possible as I can get sample opencv projects working but they already have the set up within them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

according to [this link](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/), IntelliJ haven't supported NDK but is planning to integrate it soon

Comment: I was looking for this too, the link on jetbrains blog was really helpful. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use Android Studio which is powered by IntelliJ. But It still not natively supporting Android NDK. But  you can make NDK application with the help of javah command which is coming from Java JDK. This video(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFtxo7rr2HQ) will explain how to do, in a really simple way. This answer may not helpful for you. But someone will be benefited.